# How to create a TextFree search in mongoDB with Micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-data

I am using reactive MongoDb, and trying to implement Free Text search based on the weight

```
implementation("io.micronaut.mongodb:micronaut-mongo-reactive")
```

on below POJO

```
public class Product {
    @BsonProperty("_id")
    @BsonId
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private float price;
    private String description;
}
```

Tried this simple example

```
public Flowable<List<Product>> findByFreeText(String text) {
    LOG.info(String.format("Listener --> Listening value = %s", text));
    Flowable.fromPublisher(this.repository.getCollection("product", List.class)
            .find(new Document("$text", new Document("$search", text)
                    .append("$caseSensitive", false)
                    .append("$diacriticSensitive", false)))).subscribe(item -> {
                System.out.println(item);
            }, error -> {
                System.out.println(error);
            });
    return Flowable.just(List.of(new Product()));
}
```

I don't think this is the correct way of implementing the Free Text Search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you don't need to have `Flowable` with `List` of `Product` because `Flowable` can manage more then one value unlike `Single`. So, it is enough to have `Flowable<Product>`. Then you can simply return the `Flowable` instance from `find` method.

Text search can be then implemented like this:

```java
public Flowable<Product> findByFreeText(final String query) {
    return Flowable.fromPublisher(repository.getCollection("product", Product.class)
        .find(new Document("$text",
            new Document("$search", query)
                .append("$caseSensitive", false)
                .append("$diacriticSensitive", false)
        )));
}
```

Then it is up to the consumer of the method how it subscribes to the result `Flowable`. In controller you can directly return the `Flowable` instance. If you need to consume it somewhere in your code you can do `subscribe()` or `blockingSubscribe()` and so on.

And you can of course test it by JUnit like this:

```java
@MicronautTest
class SomeServiceTest {
    @Inject
    SomeService service;

    @Test
    void findByFreeText() {
        service.findByFreeText("test")
            .test()
            .awaitCount(1)
            .assertNoErrors()
            .assertValue(p -> p.getName().contains("test"));
    }
}
```

**Update:** you can debug communication with MongoDB by setting this in *logback.xml* (Micronaut is using Logback as a default logging framework) logging config file:

```xml
<configuration>
    ....
    <logger name="org.mongodb" level="debug"/>
</configuration>
```

Then you will see this in the log file:

```
16:20:21.257 [Thread-5] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Sending command '{"find": "product", "filter": {"$text": {"$search": "test", "$caseSensitive": false, "$diacriticSensitive": false}}, "batchSize": 2147483647, "$db": "some-database"}' with request id 6 to database some-database on connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:1634}] to server localhost:27017
16:20:21.258 [Thread-8] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - 16:20:21.258 [Thread-7] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Execution of command with request id 6 completed successfully in 2.11 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:1634}] to server localhost:27017
```

Then you can copy the command from log and try it in MongoDB CLI or you can install [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) where you can play with that more and see whether the command is correct or not.

Comment: Any idea how do I set the logger for the mongoDb in micronaut ?? The search is not working for me? I have update the code

Comment: Is there any option to add on the application.yml file ?

Comment: Can you please also help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247414/reactive-and-non-blocking-method-micronaut-with-apache-kafka I am struggling from so long

Comment: Add logger into _logback.xml_ file as described in the answer and watch the log file. You can then try the same command in MongoDB CLI or you can install [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) where you can play with that more and see whether the command is correct.

Do you really store `List<Product>` in the Mongo collection? Isn't it rather collection of `Product`?

Comment: Yeah, it is a collection of products.

Comment: thank you it is working, can you please help me return value in kafka producer from the listener  as describe in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247414/reactive-and-non-blocking-method-micronaut-with-apache-kafka

Comment: I don't have any experience with Kafka yet, but I'll look on it in next days ;-)