# Getting the POJO property name in micronaut 2.1.2

Tags: java, introspection, micronaut, micronaut-rest

Trying to get the POJO property name in Micronaut application. I have the below POJO class

```
@Introspected
public class Product {
    @BsonProperty("_id")
    @BsonId
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private float price;
    private String description;

    // Getter and setter
}
```

I know we can get the property using `Introspected`

The below code gives me all the property in an array form.

```
 final BeanIntrospection<Product> introspection = BeanIntrospection.getIntrospection(Product.class);
 var product = introspection.getPropertyNames();
```

Now the product holds string of property names,

```
[0] name
[1] price
[2] description
```

I need to get the individual property as below instead of foreach on the `product`

Instead of getting through the array, is there any way to access it directly similar to Lombok as below

```
var desc = Product.Fields.description
var name = Product.Fields.name
var price = Product.Fields.price
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#introspection with explanation how yo use BeanIntrospection API

Comment: From the document I didn't get any reference for the individual property. I can see the method for to retrieve all the properties  ' introspection.getPropertyNames()'

Comment: The title is currently `"Getting the POJO property name in micronaut"` - Are you really trying to get the property names, or do you want the property values?

Comment: I am trying to get the property names, similar to this Product.Fields.name

Comment: It isn't really clear what you need to do.  Do you just need a list of all fields that are declared in the class?  All the properties (not the same as a field) declared in the class?  Something else?

Comment: I have updated the question please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead of getting through the array, is there any way to access it
> directly similar to Lombok as below:

```
var desc = Product.Fields.description 
var name = Product.Fields.name
var price = Product.Fields.price
```

No.  There is no such API to support a syntax like that.

Comment: FYI... In a comment that was attached to an answer I deleted, the OP said "I am trying to get the name of the property not the value".

Comment: Thank you for that, do you have any example for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247414/reactive-and-non-blocking-method-micronaut-with-apache-kafka, I am still not able to solve what I am missing